# What Berachah do you make on a kiwi berry?

Tags: halacha, blessing, fruits

What Berachah does one make on a [kiwi berry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinidia_arguta)? It grows on a perennial vine, which can climb very high (ha'etz) or snake along the ground (ha'adamah).

Comment: It's also supposed to be delicious.

Comment: Regular kiwi seems to grow on a very very similar plant.

Comment: @double aa so it seems. I didn't realize that was the case.

Comment: Hmm, I disagree with the edits (though I understand them). Is it necessary to provide options? Should I also state that it's not one of the five grains and therefore not Mezonoth? I think my question provided all the relevant information, and by leaving it without suggested answers a person is less likely to question why I chose those suggestions to the exclusion of other options.

Comment: shehechiyanu :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's a Haeitz.

Sources: [brochos.com](http://www.brochos.com/item/185524) which appears to be from [the CRC](http://www.crcweb.org/faq/faqanswer.php?faqid=7).